# Trying to learn how to use classes with javascript, not sure how to initialize class correctly

Tags: javascript

Not sure why this construction of a class is not working, maybe I'm just calling the function in the wrong way? Here is my code:

```
  function zeros(bits, pattern) {
    this.bits = bits;
    this.pattern = pattern;
  };

  zeros.prototype.short = function() {
    return this.bits.match(this.pattern)[0].length;
  };

  heyJude = zeros('1100110011001100000011000000111111001100111111001111110000000000000011001111110011111100111111000000110011001111110000001111110011001100000011', /([0]).*?\1+/);
  console.log(heyJude.short());
```

Comment: Worth noting that JavaScript doesn't have classes in the sense that class-based OOP languages like Java and C# do. JavaScript uses prototypical inheritance (an object has a reference to another object which is its prototype, from which it can inherit properties). What you have above is a *constructor function* (`zeros`) and associated object (`zeros.prototype`). You use it with `new`, which creates a new object backed by the object that `zeros.prototype` points to, then calls `zeros` with `this` referring to that new object. ES2015 adds `class`, which is primarily just more convenient syntax.

Comment: Perhaps also worth noting that the overwhelming convention in JavaScript is to name constructor functions with an initial capital letter, e.g. `Zeros` rather than `zeros`, whereas other functions are (by convention) named with an initial lower-case letter.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Custom_objects) has everything you need to know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Answer (score 6):

Call it via the `new` keyword:

```
var heyJude = new zeros('...');
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize the object using the `new` operator

This will instantiate an instance of your zeros class.

```
var heyJude = new zeros('110.....
```

Taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) (modified for context):

> When the code `new zeros(...)` is executed, the following things happen:
>
> 1. A new object is created, inheriting from `zeros.prototype`.
> 2. The constructor function `zeros` is called with the specified arguments and `this` bound to the newly created object. `new zeros` is equivalent to `new zeros()`, i.e. if no argument list is specified, zeros is called without arguments.
> 3. The object returned by the constructor function becomes the result of the whole `new` expression. If the constructor function doesn't explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is used instead. (Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can choose to do so if they want to override the normal object creation process.)

Comment: When quoting, use blockquotes to avoid the appearance of plagarism.

Comment: Thanks again! @T.J.Crowder